# Webdriver io - Getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Getting  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

```
it('Checkbox', async () => {
    browser.url('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/')
    const element = await $$("input[type='checkbox']")
    browser.pause(3000)
    await element[1].click()
    console.log(await element[1].isSelected())
    browser.saveScreenshot('screenshot.png')
})
```

Comment: there is no value at index 1 in the element array. try console logging the element array and see whats in it. If there is only one item, try element[0] as arrays in js are 0 indexed

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that it's not possible to read the element `.click` from `element[1]` because there's nothing in `element[1]` - it is null because there's no second element in that array. If you are unsure of the structure inside of `element` you could do `console.log(element)`, or `console.log(JSON.stringify(element))`.